# Replace outliers with mean of the specific row

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I need to convert this 2005 data with the mean of this "ROW".
I don't know how to take mean of a selected row.

[image]

I tried a lot for a solution but didn't find.
Just help me with how to take the mean/median of a selected value across its row.

Comment: What is considered an outlier? Also, instead of having a screenshot of your data frame, you can insert a smaller sample in your question.

Comment: [Do not post images, post code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)